# Rewrite useEffect hook from componentDidUpdate lifecycle method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Suppose we have an input for buyer id and we want to fetch the buyer details each time the buyerId is changed.
The following code looks like this for class components

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps,prevState) {
  if (this.state.buyerId !== prevState.buyerId) {
    this.props.fetchBuyerData(this.state.buyerId); // some random API to search for details of buyer
  }
}
```

But if we want to use useEffect hook inside a functional component how would we control it. How can we compare the previous props with the new props.

If I write it as per my understanding it will be somewhat like this.

```
useEffect(() => {
    props.fetchBuyerData(state.buyerId); 
}, [state.buyerId]);
```

But then react's hooks linter suggests that I need to include props into the dependency array as well and if I include props in the dependency array, useEffect will be called as soon as props changes which is incorrect as per the requirement.
Can someone help me understand why props is required in dependency array if its only purpose is to make an API call.
Also is there any way by which I can control the previous state or props to do a deep comparison or maybe just control the function execution inside useEffect.

Comment: Your usage of `this` keyword is incorrect. How do you use `useState`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deconstruct props either in the function declaration or inside the component. When `fetchBuyerData` is used inside the `useEffect` hook, then only it needs to be listed as a dependency instead of all of `props`:

```
// deconstruct in declaration
function MyComponent({ fetchBuyerData }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    // caveat: something is wrong with the use of `this.state` here
    fetchBuyerData(this.state.buyerId); 
  }, [fetchBuyerData, state.buyerId]);
}

// deconstruct inside component
function MyComponent(props) {
  const { fetchBuyerData } = props;
  useEffect(() => {
    // caveat: something is wrong with the use of `this.state` here
    fetchBuyerData(this.state.buyerId); 
  }, [fetchBuyerData, state.buyerId]);
}
```

Comment: But if fetchBuyerData(an action depicting an API call) has no purpose other than fetching the data of buyer, why should it be included in the dependency array. I am not able to digest this fact. Can you help with that.

Comment: ESLint has no way of knowing that a reference will remain constant when the program is executed, ESLint is a static analysis tool. _You_ know the function won't change, but it is impossible for ESLint to know that the reference will remain constant at runtime because ESLint does not run your code.

Comment: The ESLint hooks plugin has special handling for the callbacks returned from `useState` (https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/1b7b3592f4713b3a53709554aefd1d20e9a0a6a5/packages/eslint-plugin-react-hooks/src/ExhaustiveDeps.js#L150-L160) In the future it could be possible annotate values you know won't change, but for now they all should be listed in the deps array.

Answer (score 0):

I'd assume you're rewriting your class component info functional one. Then you'd be better off including your `fetch` request right where you set new `state.bayerId` (I assume it's not an external prop). Something like:

```js
const [buyerId, setBuyerId] = React.useState('')

const handleOnChange = (ev) => {
  const { value } = ev.target

  if (value !== buyerId) {
    props.fetchBuyerData(value)
    setBuyerId(value)
  }
...

  return (
    <input onChange={handleOnChange} value={buyerId} />
...
```

The code snippet is somewhat suboptimal. For production I'd assume wrap change handler into `useCallback` for it to not be recreated on each render.

Comment: This is more of an example but the real time applicability makes me do api calls inside the useEffect when certain state is changed and when that is the case why is there need to include the props.fetchBuyerData into the dependency array. That is very things are a bit unclear to me.

Comment: If `buyerId` is an external prop inside `state` object then just use it as supposed. Just correct your code. there is no `this` inside useEffect arrow function. Use `state.buyerId` inside `fetchBuyerData` call